# Passing multiple args to multiprocessing worker method

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, args

```
def main():
    ip_address = ['172.16.{}.{}'.format(rack_number, box_number) for box_number in stb_list]
full_path = su_path+baseline+'\\'+started_date
    cur.execute(
    "SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(started,'%Y%m%d') "
    "FROM results_tests "
    "WHERE results_test_id = {} ".format(test_number)
)

started_date = cur.fetchone()[0]
```

I would like to pass these three arguments to the multiprocessing worker method.

```
def worker(ip, ):
```

Inside this method, I need to get ip address, full_path and started variables.

```
if __name__=='__main__':

autodb = autodb_connect()
db = bw_dj_connect()

ips = main()

pid = os.getpid()

print('Main Process is started and PID is: ' + str(pid))

start_time = time.time()

process_list = []

for ip in ips:
    p = Process(target=worker, args=(ip, ))
    p.start()
    p.join()
    child_pid = str(p.pid)
    print('PID is:' + child_pid)
    process_list.append(child_pid)

child = multiprocessing.active_children()
print process_list

while child != []:
    time.sleep(1)
    child = multiprocessing.active_children()


print ' All processes are completed successfully ...'
print '_____________________________________'
print(' All processes took {} second!'.format(time.time()-start_time))
```

How I can pass another two arguments to worker function? Any helps would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which "these three arguments" are you talking about?  Please fix your indenting, your code isn't clear this way.  You can copy & paste your original, then mark it in the SO-editor and press Ctrl-k to indent it properly.  Did you try to just pass three arguments to the `worker()` by giving `args=(ip, foo, bar)` and defining worker as `def worker(ip, foo, bar):`?  What was the outcome?

Comment: hi @Alfe These three arguments inside the main function. ip_address which I already passed to worker method. I also need to pass full_path and started_date variables to worker method. Thanks

Comment: The issue isn't clear. Why don't you just define `worker` to take multiple arguments and then pass multiple arguments in `p = Process(target=worker, args=(ip, arg2, arg3))`? The only limitation seems to be typing the code out?

Comment: Hi @roganjosh Thanks for your comment. This is something I am trying to achieve. As far as I know, Python methods return tuples for returning multiples args.  return (started_date, full_path, ip_address).     started_date = main()[0]
  full_path = main()[1]
   ips = main()[2]
That does not work.

Comment: Ok, so I think the issue is that you have everything packed into `ips = main()`? First, `main` doesn't return anything at the moment (well, it returns `None`) because you haven't been explicit in what should be returned. So first, at end of `main`, put `return started_date, full_path, ip_address`. Unpack these values by changing `ips = main()` to `started_date, full_path, ip_address = main()`. Change `def worker(ip, )` to `def worker(start_date, full_path, ip_add)`.

Comment: Finally, call it with `p = Process(target=worker, args=(started_date, full_path, ip_address ))`. This makes it clearer where all your values are coming from, otherwise you'd need to use `*args` to unpack the tuple inside the worker I guess.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot for your help @roganjosh. that works fine ;)